# SSH Connection to remote Linux server but without using 3rd party Lib

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I am trying to make a small Java utility for a client which connects to the remote Linux server from windows and give monitoring results to a Java text view frame(basically run few basic commands on queue managers and Space Usage and save output to a file or return back to JAVA program).

But the problem is I cannot use any third party lib like Jsch or Ganymed.

I there any other way I can get this done ?

Haven't code anything as I am not sure if it can be done without these lib.

Comment: Why can't you use those libraries?

Comment: My client has a very strict policy of not using third party lib. At least not unless its absolutely necessary and then too its a long process to get it approved and download it to the secured client network.

Comment: Your client is idiot. You are welcome to tell him abut this. If you want reference, I am here.

Comment: Feeling is mutual my friend but got to earn a living cannot help it :)

Comment: Is there a fixed set of commands (I mean the commands do not change)? Do you do have access to linux to create script on linux box?

Comment: Yes I have access to Linux sever and I will be executing a script only

Answer (score 0):

SSH is not a trivial protocol and its implementation is not a trivial task. If you are on Linux you can run ssh command line like any external process from java. But your are on windows. So, you can install ssh for windows (there are several implementations) and then run the command line from java. This will work but requires pre-requisites and indeed using 3rd party too.

Other way is to take one of available open source library and either pack it together with your code or just take its source code and incorporate into your project (if you do not violate the license agreement). Obviously it does not mean that you do not use 3rd party but just hide this face. However customer that can *require* not to use 3rd party should be stupid enough to not to detect your trick.

BTW to be on the safe side you can take open source project as source, change its package name and compile it together with your project. In this case it is really difficult to catch you.

Bottom line: good luck with it.

Comment: So what I can make out from your answer is that I need to look into executing commands from 3rd party client installed on Windows such as Putty or ssh client ?

Comment: This is one of possible solutions. (IMHO not the best one).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to linux machine and you want execute a sequence of commands you don't have to use ssh connection at all. Write a script on linux box and save it. To execute this script write a program (let's name it "executor") which will start a script and grab it's output. From your java application on windows connect to your "executor" program located on linux (instead of directly running script via ssh).

Your executor can be as described below:

- just your script running as cgi-bin program on apache server on linux - this way you connect to it from java application the same way as you would download any web page using java (look for examples of usage of HttpUrlConnection class)
- another java application - look for ways of communication between java apps ( RMI for example)
- ... really it can be anything which can execute linux script and to which you can talk using simpler protocol than ssh...